# cooldown chemistry of seasoning cast iron with flaxseed

Tags: cast-iron, chemistry, seasoning-pans

So I have started seasoning cookware with thin layers of flaxseed oil as per the advice from @sheryl_canter with simply outstanding results. Thank you Sheryl! I have a mountain of pans to process so I'm starting to wonder how necessary it is to begin from a cold start and let the oven completely cool with the door shut before the next cycle.

If I wait until the oven cools to 100°C then open the door to accelerate cooling, then re-season and proceed as soon as I can handle them, am I going to miss out on much plasticisation chemistry?

My oven does about 285°C at full tilt with the fan on and takes about five hours to become cool enough to handle with the door shut and the power off.